# Java subclass using data from another subclass of the same superclass

Tags: java, superclass

I have created 3 classes, one superclass "a" and under a two subclasses "b" and "c". I am creating an instance of c, give it an integer "n" and then use subclass b to do some calculation. The problem I am having is that when I create an instance c to call b, the data technically belong to the superclass a/c right? so when i create an instance of b with

b b_instance = new b();

inside the instance of c,
the b calc() function I call would return 0. I guess it's because b has it's own eco-sphere of data?

How do I do this?

2)

Also, how do i call the superclass function of the same name?

Thanks!

```
public class prog
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {  
       c c1 = new c();
       c1.run();

   }
}

class a
{
   private int number;

   void set_number(int n)
   {
      number = n;
   }

   int get_number()
   {
      return number;
   }

   int calc()
   {
      return number*2;
   }

}

class b extends a
{
   int calc()
   {
      // calling the superclass function calc, then subtract
      return super.calc() - get_number();
   }
}

class c extends a
{


   void run()
   {
      set_number(1);
      b b1 = new b();
      System.out.println(b1.calc());
   }

}
```

infinite loop problem

```
public class prog
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {  
      c c1 = new c();
      c1.run();

   }
}

class a
{   
   void calc_a()
   {
      System.out.println("")  ;
   }

   void calc_b()
   {
      calc_a(); // meaning the calc_a() in the superclass
   }
}

class b extends a
{
   void calc_a()
   {
      super.calc_b();
   }
}

class c extends a
{
   void run()
   {
      b b1 = new b();
      b1.calc_b();
   }
}
```

Comment: If `c` "needs" to call `b`, why doesn't `c` extend from `b`?

Comment: i see what you mean, but this part of my homework problem dictates that construct.

Comment: the data is entered inside c but i need b to process it, while both c and b belongs to a?

Comment: The data belongs to the "instance" of the object, so `c` and `b` have their own copies of the data

Comment: i get that, and i am trying to use data in c to process in b

Comment: Then pass the data from `c` to `b` :/

Comment: You should look long and hard at whether your homework really requires this construct in this way. Because all common coding practices are screaming that this is a terrible idea going against most concepts of OOP. It’s possible that the homework is flawed but also possible you’re interpreting it incorrectly.

Comment: i am quite certain i need to do it this way :(

Comment: your edit is confusing me, it looks like you have 2 class definitions for a, b and c.

Comment: oh sorry, the 2nd part of the edit is the 2nd problem

Answer (score 1):

> b b_instance = new b();
>
> inside the instance of c, the b calc() function I call would return 0.
>   I guess it's because b has it's own eco-sphere of data?
>
> How do I do this?

A "couple" of possible ways.  I'd consider extending `c` from `b`, this way `c` gets all the functionality of `a` and `b`, something like...

```
class c extends b {

    void run() {
        set_number(1);
        System.out.println(calc());
    }

}
```

IF, however, this is not feasible (for some reason or other), then you need to pass the value that `c` has to `b`, something like...

```
class c extends a {

    void run() {
        set_number(1);
        b b1 = new b();
        b1.set_number(get_number());
        System.out.println(b1.calc());
    }

}
```

Now, having said that, this "smells" to me.  What's the point of extending from `a` just so `c` can perform `b`?  It would set off alarm bells to me.

The problem is, if your call `c#calc`, it's just going to `a`'s `calc` method ... which, based on `run`, doesn't seem to be what you want to achieve, so it's all just a big mess

> 2)
>
> Also, how do i call the superclass function of the same name?

Because calling `calc` directly would cause a `StackOverflowError` because you're constantly calling yourself.

In this case, you're taking the operation that `a` is doing and making a modification to it.  This is a common practice in OO languages.

## Side notes...

Java (and the Java community) already have a well defined set of coding practices. You should take the time to learn them, it will make your code easier to read and make it easier for you to read other peoples codes.

Start with [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

Class names should start with a capital letter and methods are in `camelCase`, for example...

```
class A {

    private int number;

    void setNumber(int n) {
        number = n;
    }

    int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    int calc() {
        return number * 2;
    }

}
```

## Updated...

```
class a {

    void calc_a() {
        System.out.println("");
    }

    void calc_b() {
        calc_a(); // meaning the calc_a() in the superclass
    }

}

class b extends a {

    void calc_a() {
        super.calc_b();
    }
}

class c extends a {

    void run() {
        b b1 = new b();
        b1.calc_b();
    }

}
```

The question you need to ask yourself is, why does `b` need to override `calc_a`?  Why not override `calc_b`? It would solve the issue

> how do i override it?

```
class b extends a {

    //void calc_a() {
    //    super.calc_b();
    //}
    @Override 
    void calc_b() {
        super.calc_b();
    }
}
```

Comment: b1.set_number(get_number());   this line solved the problem of data, thank you

Comment: if I need to call both calc() in the subclass and superclass in the same line, how do I differentiate between the two?

Comment: how about, I have a subclass calc_a() using super.calc_b(),  and super.calc_b() is supposed to call calc_a() in the superclass, but instead i get infinite loop because the super_calc_b() calls the subclass calc_a() ?

Comment: public class prog
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {  
      c c1 = new c();
      c1.run();
   
   }
}

class a
{   
   void calc_a()
   {
      System.out.println("")  ;
   }
   
   void calc_b()
   {
      calc_a(); // meaning the calc_a() in the superclass
   }
   
   
}

class b extends a
{
   void calc_a()
   {
      super.calc_b();
   }
}

class c extends a
{

   
   void run()
   {
      b b1 = new b();
      b1.calc_b();
   }
   
}

Comment: i modified the original post

Comment: SuperClass has function A() and B() and subclass only has a(),  a() calls B() which needs A() so a() ends up getting called and causes infinite loop, because while there is super.A(), I can't seem to put super.A() inside B(), because B() is in a superclass

Comment: Long answer is - don't.  Why would `B` need to override `calc_a` when it's only calling `calc_b` - why not override `calc_b` directly?

Comment: how do i override it?

Comment: You overrode `calc_a`, you do it the same way

Comment: calc_b needs somethign from calc_a to go back to calc_a in class B

Comment: @MichaelC It's time to stop talking "hypothetical" and start talk "actual", as this could change the way you approach the problem

Comment: the actual problem is I have to come up with a way to do this:  have a subclass method called calc_a() to call superclass calc_b() which needs superclass calc_a(), and call the calc_a() in superclass instead of subclass calc_a()

Comment: it has to work like that, somehow, i realize it's all backwards.

Comment: @MichaelC I need the actual worded assignment, not your interpretation of it, otherwise we're just going to end up wasting each others time

Comment: @MichaelC At this point in time, would recommend abandoning this question and starting again. Start with the actual assignment you've been set, not your interpretation of it, and provide the work you've tried to solve it.  We will have a better understand of the overall issue and can then provide you with better support